# What is usually open in Vienna during Christmas?

Tags: sightseeing, shopping, vienna, christmas

I'll be spending my a few days of my holidays in Vienna and I found the city quite dead today (24th). It was such a disaster to find a nice restaurant to have dinner and every single shop/restaurant was closed. I'd like to know a few breakfast/brunch cafes to have a breakfast tomorrow (25th). Could anyone recommend some places to have a breakfast/brunch on Christmas holidays?

Comment: Both the 25th and the 26th are holidays in Austria and shops are closed in general (except supermarkets in train stations). Also, many cafes will be closed since the owners want to spend Christmas with their families (or close since their customers stay home). However, many museums will be open tomorrow and the day after (e.g., Kunsthistorisches Museum, Albertina, ...) and you can also go to cultural performances (the Staatsoper has Die Zauberflöte tomorrow, for example). That being said, your question for cafe recommendations sounds too opinion-based to remain open in my opinion.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. Unfortunately recommending places worth visiting is off topic on this site. Since we all have different personal preferences, what might be worth visiting for me might not be for you. A similar reasoning holds for "nice" places to have breakfast. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: @JoErNano thank you for your advice. I edited the question in an attemp to make it on topic, hope it suffices.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @martin.koeberl. Are there christmas markets in the city which are open during these days?

Comment: @Gigili I'm not sure that solely adding the "open around Christmas" constraint to the question makes it less opinion based. It does narrow it down marginally however we all still have different personal preferences when it comes to sightseeing. Don't hesitate to try voting for it to be reopened to see what the community thinks.

Comment: It might be a good plan to go out into the countryside near the city, see nature rather than culture.

Comment: Most christmas markets closed yesterday or two days ago but the ones in Schönbrunn and at Rathausplatz are open.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Christmas is over for this year, but I think it would be useful to see an explanation what is generally open over the holidays and what is not.

Answer (score 3):

In Vienna, the Christmas holiday is celebrated in homes, and most restaurants and shops are closed from December 24 to December 26. Traditionally, the biggest observation is on Christmas Eve, the 24th, the official public holidays and closures are on the 25th and 26th. As Christmas Eve is the big event, some places have opening hours on the the following two days (e.g., museums, cinemas, clubs).

Usually [Vienna Tourism/Wien Turismus](https://www.wien.info/en/shopping-wining-dining/restaurants/christmas-restaurants), a service of the Vienna Tourist Board, lists restaurants open on the 24th, district by district (currently the 2017 coverage).

The independent Vienna Unwrapped, in its [Christmas Dinner and Christmas Day In Vienna 2017](https://www.vienna-unwrapped.com/christmas-dinner-and-christmas-day-in-vienna/) article, suggests heading to hotels with restaurants, along with tips on what attractions are open (sightseeing, markets, concerts).

Resources:

[Christmas in Vienna 2018](http://www.visitingvienna.com/entertainment/christmas-in-vienna/)

[Visiting Vienna Christmas opening hours 2018 for museums and palaces](http://www.visitingvienna.com/sights/christmas-opening-hours/)

[7 things to do when Vienna closes down for the Christmas holidays](http://www.viennawurstelstand.com/article/7-things-to-do-when-vienna-closes-down-for-the-christmas-holidays/)

[8 places to enjoy a cosy Christmas dinner in Vienna](https://www.thelocal.at/20161202/8-places-to-enjoy-a-cosy-christmas-dinner-in-vienna)

[Where to have Christmas Dinner in Vienna](https://austrianadaptation.com/where-to-have-christmas-dinner-in-vienna/)

[10 Things to Do in Vienna This Christmas](https://theculturetrip.com/europe/austria/articles/10-things-to-do-in-vienna-this-christmas/)

[Vienna - Tope 10 things to do in Christmas and Winter Time](https://www.theviennablog.com/2017/11/24/top-10-things-to-do-in-vienna-in-winter-and-christmas-time/)